# Make an array with all the values from one array which match the value in another array in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I have a database class like this:

```
public partial class Colour
    {
        public int ColourID { get; set; }
        public string Colour1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Another class like this:

```
public partial class RangeColour
{
    public int RangeColourID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RangeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ColourID { get; set; }
}
```

and a third class like this:

```
public partial class Range
    {
        public int RangeID { get; set; }
        public string RangeName { get; set; }
    }
```

Each `Range` instance can have many colours from the `Colour` class. All the Ranges are and their colours are linked in the `RangeColour` class.

This relationship is established as follows: `RangeID` in the `Range` table is a primary key to `RangeID` in the `RangeColour` table.

In like manner `ColourID` in the `Colour` table is a primary key to `ColourID` in the `RangeColour` table.

I get an `IEnumerable` of a specific range in my c# method as follows:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller

{
    Entities db = new Entities();

    public ActionResult Product(int id)
    {         

        IEnumerable<RangeColour> colran = db.RangeColours.Where(c => c.RangeID == id);
       //other code
    }
}
```

Now that I have got an `IEnumerable` of the `RangeColours` table of all the `colourID` which belong to that `RangeID` how can I make a new `IEnumerable` which has all the `Colour1` that go with those `ColourID`'s values from the `Colour` table in it to? I'm sure this can be accomplished with a lambda expression of some sort.

Comment: It appears you are working with entity framework. You will get a lot better performance of your join if you work with  `IQueryable<RangeColour> colran =` instead of `IEnumerable<RangeColour> colran =`. EDIT, or even better do `var colran =` Then you can start working with anonymous types and projections.

Comment: How would I make this join using an IQueryable? I want to use whatever is best but i'm still not sure how to make this join. My primary concern here is not on what type of collection to use but how to join two collections of data with matching values into a new collection.

Comment: It depends on how you need to use the data, do you want a list of classes that look like `class ColorAndRange {  public string Colour1 { get; set; } public string RangeName { get; set; } }` where you have duplicate `Colour1` entries or do you want a class that looks like  `class ColorAndRange {  public string Colour1 { get; set; } public string IEnumerable<RangeName> { get; set; } }` and you only get one record per Colour1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534644(v=vs.110).aspx) extension on IQueryable to get the colors.

```
IQueryable<Colour> colors = db.Colors.Join(
    db.RangeColours.Where(c => c.RangeID == item.RangeID),
    c => c.ColourID,
    r => r.ColourID,
    (c, r) => c);
```

Then you can select your Colour1 strings if you need. And use `ToList()` if you need it in memory.

```
colors.Select(c => c.Colour1).ToList()
```